# Tableau: Creating Dynamic Filter to exclude names

Tags: if-statement, parameters, tableau-api

I have been working on this for the better part of the day and would like to crowd source as I must just be missing something simple.

I would like to use a parameter control to create a dynamic filter that would exclude the names of individuals that have already participated in an event. For example in the following list of two fields:

Name-Event Name

Carl-Agriculture

Carl-Agriculture

Carl-Agriculture

Jodie-Business

Jodie-Agriculture

Jodie-Agriculture

Pam-Business

Pam-Business

Pam-Business

if the parameter was set to Agriculture, only Pam would show up on the list, and if it was set to Business only Carl would show up. This list will help stakeholders send invitations to potentially interested parties.

I have tried so many calculations including the parameter itself in IF statements, IIF statements, CASE statements, etc. I've also tried creating a second calculation to work off of the first but am still striking out.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is too broad a question.  If you have a specific part of a specific piece of code you'd like help with, please post it.  And show the expected result, and point to the line or lines that aren't working or you're confused by.

Comment: The problem is, I can't get to a point where I am confident that I have the right code. It is more of a Tableau functionality problem. I have attached the workbook here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/969qikft7tunf9t/Names%20and%20Events.twbx?dl=0..... Question is, how do I get those with 0 of the event chosen to STAY in visual, and those that have already participated to be excluded.

Comment: DropBox require a user account and I don't want to hassle the login.  I am not knowledgeable about tableau I was just doing StackOverflow.com "civic duty" (it's a community moderated site) by working on the [review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review) to improve the quality of first posts by members and noticed that your post does not really conform to the guidelines and less likely to get a good response.  See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/review) and [On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got most of the way there on your own. To finish the job:

1. Place Name on the filter shelf
2. Select "Use all" on the General tab of the filter panel
3. Select "By field:" on the Condition tab of the filter panel
4. Choose the "If Exclusion Statement" field, Count aggregation function (NOT Sum in this case), and set the test to "= 0"

The effect of this filter is equivalent to the SQL `group by Name having Count(If Exclusion Statement) = 0`

Comment: Thank youi Alex. I am so close. However, when I complete the task that way, I lose my entire visual. Should I use greater than 0? Is there a problem because I used "Number of Records" rather than putting together a calculation?

Comment: Use the COUNT() aggregation, not SUM(). My fault for originally saying both would work. Count() returns the number of records that have a non-null value. Your calculated field does not have an else clause, so will effectively "return" null when the if condition fails. That's all good practice, but means you need to use Count() instead of Sum() in this case.

Comment: @JasonAltman Glad to help. It was an interesting question. P.S. The SO way to say thanks is to accept and upvote the answer :-)